# Excel, Trying to use Row() to reference cell for Indirect() pull of data from other tab

Tags: excel, row, formula

```
Target Tab Name     Data (date)     Formula used to grab it

1   RTP SVC MCU         01/31/15        ='RTP SVC MCU'!G1
2   RTP SVC MCU         01/31/15        =INDIRECT("'" & B2 & "'!G1")
3   RTP SVC MCU         #REF!           =INDIRECT("'" & ("B" & ROW()) & "'!G1")

Row test        B5  ="B" & ROW()
```

On my worksheet I'm creating a summary tab that will pull various bits of information from other tabs. The example marked 1 grabbed the date from tab "RTP SVC MCU", cell G1, simple and straight-forward.

Example 2 does the same, but I removed the explicitly defined tab name and replaced it with a reference to the tab name which already exists for the summary in B14.

Example 3 attempts to do the same, but without explicitly defining the cell containing the Tab name. Basically I'd like to grab the tab name from the Target Tab Name column for it's own Row number so that all the date columns (and others) can be populated without just dragging the formula down with Auto Fill because there need to be blank rows between the summaries.

Long story short, I'm trying to combine the effects of my rows marked 2 and "Row Test".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need another INDIRECT:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & (INDIRECT("B" & ROW())) & "'!G1")
```

Comment: Holy hell you're awesome. Thank you.